# golang calculate area of intersection of two geo regions

Tags: go, geometry, geospatial

I have a list of Geo Regions as lat,long coordinates. I am able to find out the regions that are overlapping (Using MongoDB geoIntersect operator).

Once I find the overlapping regions I would like to find out the amount of overlap. I would be using area of the regions as a measure. meaning if regions one area is 1 sqkm and regions 2 is 2 sqkm then I would like to know the overlap of these regions in sq km.

I checked code given at [Sutherland-Hodgman_polygon_clipping#Go](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sutherland-Hodgman_polygon_clipping#Go) but I am struggling to use geo coordinates instead of Cartesian coordinates.

As shown in the figure, there are 2 regions overlapping each other, i would like to find out the area (in sq km) of the green colored area.

i also checked the famous S2 library Loop structure, but failed to use it to find the intersection area [S2 type Loop](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/golang/geo@v0.0.0-20210211234256-740aa86cb551/s2#Loop)

i am using Golang for development.

[image]

Comment: C++ version of S2 library has S2BooleanOperation class that supports intersection. I could not find it in Golang version, it seems to have Union only. But if you can drop to C++, see https://github.com/google/s2geometry/blob/master/src/s2/s2boolean_operation.h

Comment: @MichaelEntin right, i saw this too that's why i explored S2 library but could not find intersection polygon and area functionality in Golang port